# When page is refreshed data persists in localStorage but, it diappears from the display

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am working on a Vanilla JavaScript Library app with local storage. But, when the page is refreshed even though the data persists in localStorage, but it disappears from the display. When clicking the add book button the data is stored on localStorage, and it persists even after the page is refreshed, but the book cards on display, disappear. I can't find out what is wrong with the code.

Github Address:    https://github.com/bdarab/online-library

```
  static addBookToLibrary() {
    // addBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    //   e.preventDefault();
      const displayContainer = document.querySelector("#display");
      const displayCard = document.createElement("div");
      displayCard.classList.add("card");
      displayCard.innerHTML += `
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">title:</h5>
          <h5 class="card-author">author:</h5>
          <h5 class="card-pages">pages: </h5>
        </div>
        <div class="isRead">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="isRead">
            Is it Read?
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete">
            Delete
          </button>
        </div>
      `;
      displayContainer.appendChild(displayCard);
  }  // });
}

// localStorage setup
/* 3. Store Class */


class Store {
  static getBooks() {
    let books;
    if (localStorage.getItem("books") === null) {
      books = [];
    } else {
      books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("books"));
    }
    return books;
  }

  static addBook(book) {
    const books = Store.getBooks();
    books.push(book);
    localStorage.setItem("books", JSON.stringify(books));
  }

  static removeBook(title) {
    const books = Store.getBooks();
    books.forEach((book, index) => {
      if (book.title === title) {
        books.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
    localStorage.setItem("books", JSON.stringify(books));
  }
}
```

Comment: Try and create a minimal example that replicates the issue and fits in the question. Linking to the Github repo is not encouraged, as that may change in the future. About the question, it seems to boil down to the initial `getBooks` call. What does `getBooks` return after page reload?

Comment: It returns books array. Doesn't it?

Comment: Ideally, it should. But you're saying the data is not persisted after page reload, so that's where the debugging should begin.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried correcting what I didn't think was correct, and it worked well

demo jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/uv7qnt0x/
[image]

```
  // missing parameter => boook and 
  // data has not been displayed on the list => ${book.title} ...etc
  static addBookToLibrary(book) {
    // addBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    //   e.preventDefault();
      const displayContainer = document.querySelector("#display");
      const displayCard = document.createElement("div");
      displayCard.classList.add("card");
      displayCard.innerHTML = `
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">title: ${book.title}</h5>
          <h5 class="card-author">author: ${book.author}</h5>
          <h5 class="card-pages">pages: ${book.pageNum}</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="isRead">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="isRead">
            Is it Read?
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete">
            Delete
          </button>
        </div>
      `;
      displayContainer.appendChild(displayCard);
  }  // });
}

/* 4. Event: Display Books */
// document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", DisplayBooks.displayBooks);
window.onload = function(e){
  DisplayBooks.displayBook()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, buddy! It is working fine. I am studying your changes carefully.